# svg маска на svg элементе не хочет отрабатываться в firefox

Tags: svg, firefox, mask

всем привет, просмотрел уде сушествующие посты, похожего ничего нет, в опере и хроме маска навешивается, а в огнелисе не хочет.

```
<div id='cont'>
  <svg>
    <defs>
      <mask id='rectMask' maskUnits='userSpaceOnUse' maskContentUnits='userSpaceOnUse' transform='scale(1)'>
        <rect x='0' y='0' id='maskRect'/>
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <path id='maskedPath' d='m 0,0 l 650,0 -100,850 -550,0 z' mask='url(#rectMask)'/>
    <path id='riverPath' d='m 653,0 l -100,850' mask='url(#rectMask)'/>
    <path id='notMaskedPath' d='m 655,0 l 650,0 0,850 -750,0 z'/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

стили:

```
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#cont {
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background-color:rgb(50,50,50);
}
svg {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
#maskedPath {
  stroke:none;
  fill:rgb(230,230,230);
}
#notMaskedPath {
  stroke:none;
  fill:rgb(230,230,230);
}
#riverPath {
  stroke:rgb(50,160,240);
  stroke-width:8;
  fill:none;
}
#maskRect {
  width:0px;
  height:850px;
  fill:white;
  stroke:none;
  animation: resizeMask 4s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: resizeMask 4s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: resizeMask 4s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes resizeMask {
  40% {width:670px}
  50% {width:670px}
  100% {width:0px}
}
@-webkit-keyframes resizeMask {
  40% {width:670px}
  50% {width:670px}
  100% {width:0px}
}
@-moz-keyframes resizeMask {
  40% {width:670px}
  50% {width:670px}
  100% {width:0px}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox в этом плане всегда придерживается w3.org. Если в спецификации `width` в [css-свойствах нет](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/propidx.html), то и в браузере это не будет работать. Т.е. `width` и `heigth` нельзя задавать в css, и, соответственно анимировать с помощью css. Если оно работает в хроме, то фактически, это неправильно.

Как быть? Сделайте анимацию как она должна быть, как описано в спецификации через `animate`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#cont {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#maskedPath {
  stroke: none;
  fill: rgb(230, 230, 230);
}

#notMaskedPath {
  stroke: none;
  fill: rgb(230, 230, 230);
}

#riverPath {
  stroke: rgb(50, 160, 240);
  stroke-width: 8;
  fill: none;
}

#maskRect {
  fill: white;
  stroke: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='cont'>
  <svg>
    <defs>
      <mask id='rectMask' maskUnits='userSpaceOnUse' maskContentUnits='userSpaceOnUse' >
        <rect x='0' y='0' width='670px' height='850px'  id='maskRect' >
            <animate attributeName="width" values="0;900px;0" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        </rect>
      </mask>
    </defs>
 
    <path id='maskedPath' d='m 0,0 l 650,0 -100,850 -550,0 z' mask='url(#rectMask)'/>
    <path id='riverPath' d='m 653,0 l -100,850' mask='url(#rectMask)'/>
    <path id='notMaskedPath' d='m 655,0 l 650,0 0,850 -750,0 z'/>


  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо за старание, однако смил стар, полифил к нему так же. делать два варианта под разные браузеры - мне не нра, так что я просто перевёл всё в es